# Can a 皇帝 be female?

Tags: words, gender

What would the word for empress (other than of Japan) be? Please give me the word for a ruling empress.

Comment: @broccoliforest Is there an answer to this question? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @macraf That's a mass of information, but you can search for "empress" on that page.

Comment: @broccoliforest Yes, but the relation is Japanese -> English and it doesn't seem that the English terminology there is supposed to be complete. And it stands in opposition to the answer here.

Comment: @macraf I thought it at least gave an exact answer to OP's question: "ruling empress" in Japanese. Are you looking at the question or the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [[女帝]{じょてい}](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A5%B3%E5%B8%9D).

皇帝 is also used for an empress, e.g.: [アンナ(ロシア皇帝)](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%8A_%28%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A2%E7%9A%87%E5%B8%9D%29)